# How to handle binary data in Linux

Tags: linux, command-line, binary

One of the my servers gives me data with `Content-Type: application/binary`, i.e data that I am getting looks like some alien data.

Now I need to convert that data into plain data, but I am not aware of any way to do that. I am trying to do this using the command line.

After googling, I found one way: I need to delete the first 10 char and last 8 char from my data and then use `gunzip` with that. Then I will get the original data. But when I try to delete those characters, as it is binary output, it cuts more than that or less than 10+8 characters.

Actually `echo` is not able to print the data properly. So, please, does anyone know how to handle binary data?

Comment: The binary data is in zip format

Comment: You should explain the difference between plain data and alien data.

Comment: i mean unreadable data by alien data, plain data means readable data, i m getting data just like:mU;??H%W??xA???ZQ???z???&4????????H?jl??c?3ǟ?$?G?#?)h??xKCMM?t??_
?D?K?L?X??u{?3s??9'o}??/|???o?+?r?T?5J??o?????on???Tl???C|?X?1?h???(?t???q??5?.
%b\y??:'Ƿ?M?ԋ?=E?t,?1"??R??(`??u????P?)??v?3Su???u?{?K-0 ??BD?????>??׿i8f???R??R`#`h????.?VMa???RI?c?0^???ZP?*'?y??????a2??6Ǉlw????zP?LQ{-铜??)J???9
?@?`??E?szA????EU???gi?.g=,9??@???Ĳ??#?j?޼???/~vͼ?lFC,?A\X-?J?p??dr8????DQ??? ?BঌG????i?Zu????A//k(-??i?K?I?14\n #~C?ǡ#@?i?<?

Comment: Readable by what?

Comment: if i remove first 10 and last 8 characters and pass it into gzinflate,it gives me readable data, i.e you can understand that data,above code is trimmed(as it is too much long data)

Comment: We can't read that data any more than you can. We need more information to be able to help you. How exactly are you getting this file? What kind of server? How is it "giving" it to you? Show us this "readable" data you get when passing through `gzinflate`. Is this a PHP thing? If you've saved your data in a file called `foo.bin`, what is the output of `file foo.bin`?

Comment: Problem has been solved, thanks for your support

Answer (score 1):

What your asking is quiet unclear.
what format is your file ? compressed file ? archive? compressed archive ?
what the command

```
file yourfilename
```

give as output ?
as it's binary data, what do you want to strip octect , bit ?

to strip binaries file you should considere the use of `dd`  command

```
dd if=input.bin of=output.bin bs=1 skip=X count=Y
```

Where X is the number of bytes you want to remove from the beginning, and Y is the number of bytes you want to process before the end of file.

Suppose you have a binary files which is 100 bytes in size and you want to remove the first 10 bytes and the last 5 bytes, obtaining an 85 bytes output.
The value of X will be 10, while the value of Y will be 85 (=100-10-5). You can find file size with a simple "ls" or "wc -c" command.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

The trailing characters can be ignored, you may just get a warning, so there is half the problem, so let's look at the first 10.

now the problem can be handled by dd. all we need to do is to tell it to skip one block of 10 bytes. `wget -o - http://example.com/sample-data |dd ibs=10 skip=1 of=data.zip; unzip data.zip`

Comment: got the error as: Archive:  data.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of data.zip or
        data.zip.zip, and cannot find data.zip.ZIP, period.

Comment: If i am doing the same thing with php, and after removing first 10 and last 8 characters, if i apply gzinflate(data) command, then it is giving me perfect output as i want,

Comment: Jordanm said it was in zip format but gzinflate uses gzip format, so change the unzip in my answer to gunzip.

Comment: @MDThakkar you can also run php from the commandline.

Comment: ya i have tried ur code with gunzip then it is giving me gzip: data.gz: not in gzip format

Comment: Ya i know i can run it from commandline but, my project requirement is to only using linux shell script or c,c++ code, so i cant do that